# Assign an url for every item in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to Sharepoint and I am trying to create a workflow that collects data from users and save it on a list. The idea is that the users will receive an email with an unique url to change their information at the edit item form.

I've seen some people use something like "/sites/mySite/Lists/myList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1" to edit an item. However, I have to make sure users won't be able to modify other users data by using an url hard to guess because the website will be public. Can something like this be done in sharepoint or I should look for a solution in C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sending email of item url using SPD workflow?

Comment: I think you have to break/replace list item permissions using SPD Workflow while you creating item in list . So that only user can edit item who having permissions given through WF. You will get an idea from this article https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/66248-restrict-a-sharepoint-task-to-its-assigned-user-group

Answer (score 0):

In this case , you need to adjust your `Item-level Permissions` setting to specify **which items users can read and edit**. 
as the following :

- Read items that were created by the user .
- Create items and edit items that were created by the.

**Steps :**

- Go to list Setting > Advance Setting > `Item-level Permissions`

[image]

Comment: Just to make it fully clear, this would be in combination with the solution of using `/sites/mySite/Lists/myList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1` mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know if this can work. The problem is that the sharepoint site will be accessed by outsiders (the site will be public) and I need to collect data from them. Also, I will create all the items and they are just going to edit the fields if necessary.